# Running total of every increment

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands, mariadb-10.2

I have a table `events` as follows:

```
f_id   leg   
1       1
2       1
3       1
4       2
5       2
6       3
7       1
8       1
9       2
```

I want a running total of every time the `leg` changes. Expected output:

```
f_id   leg     total_legs   
1       1         1
2       1         1
3       1         1
4       2         2
5       2         2
6       3         3
7       1         4
8       1         4
9       2         5
```

Not sure how to go about this.

```
SELECT *, @leg_var:=IF(@current_leg=leg, leg) as total_legs FROM `events`
```

This is clearly wrong.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Using MariaDB 10.2

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, CASE WHEN LAG(leg) OVER (ORDER BY f_id) = leg 
                             THEN 0 
                             ELSE 1 
                             END lag_leg
              FROM test )
SELECT f_id, leg, SUM(lag_leg) OVER (ORDER BY f_id) total_legs
FROM cte;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=58af02a9714989ce9bd5949db0f71cd0)

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of gaps-and-islands problem. In MySQL 8.0, you can use `lag()` and a cumulative `sum()`:

```
select fid, leg, sum(not leg <=> lag_leg) over(order by f_id) total_legs
from (
    select e.*, lag(leg) over(order by f_id) lag_leg
    from events e
) e
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved without window functions using variables:

```
SET @leg_var:=null;
SET @total:=0;
SELECT 
    f_id, 
    @leg_var prev_leg, 
    @total:=@total+if(@leg_var is null or @leg_var<>leg, 1, 0) as total,
    @leg_var:=leg as leg
FROM events
ORDER BY f_id;
```

[fiddle here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=97528f388a88e10524f2166e495fa601&php_version=null&sql_version=mariadb)